# React Error: 'obj' is not defined.eslint no-undef

Tags: reactjs, onclick, jsx, eslintrc

In React I have RecipeListPage.jsx with recipes. Clicking on a recipe should show RecipePage.jsx with  only the clicked recipe info. However, my onClick code gives the error  **'obj' is not defined.eslint no-undef**

```
        <Flex wrap='wrap' gap={8} justify='center' my={2}>
          {list.map((list) => (
            <Card
              bgColor='white'
              overflow='hidden'
              borderRadius={15}
              h='md'
              w='xsm'
              cursor='pointer'
              _hover={{ transform: 'scale(1.03)' }}
              key={list}
              onClick={() => clickFn(obj.recipe)}
            >
```

I've been looking if I need to change something in eslint, but seems to be fine:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:react/jsx-runtime"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["react"],
    "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": 0
    }
}
```

In my VS Code this error shows a link to the following page:
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef

Does anyone know how to solve this please?

**Update:**
I tried adding "no-undef" to eslintrc.json, that does get rid of the error. However, the code still doesn't work.

"rules": {
"no-undef": "off"
}

This just turns the warning of, but the obj still isn't defined according to browser console:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined"
This error refers to  onClick={clickFn(obj.recipe)}

Just to be sure, this is the entire RecipeListPage.jsx:

```
import { data } from '../utils/data';
import { TextInput } from '../components/ui/TextInput';
import { useState } from 'react'
import {
    Flex,
    Card,
    CardBody,
    Center,
    Text,
    Image,
    Stack,
    Tag,
    Heading,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

export const RecipeListPage = ({ clickFn }) => {
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearchField(event.target.value);
  };

  const matchedRecipe = data.hits.filter(obj =>
    obj.recipe.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()));

  let displayMatchedRecipe = data.hits;
  if (matchedRecipe.length > 0) {
    displayMatchedRecipe = matchedRecipe;
  }

  const list = displayMatchedRecipe.map(obj =>
    <>
      <Image key={obj.recipe.image}
        src={obj.recipe.image}
        h='10rem'
        w='100%'        
        mt={-1}        
        borderTopLeftRadius={15}        
        borderTopRightRadius={15}        
        objectFit='cover'  
      />
      <Text textTransform='uppercase' key={obj.recipe.mealType}>
        {obj.recipe.mealType}
      </Text>
      <Text
        fontSize={18}
        fontWeight='bold'
        textAlign='center'        
        key={obj.recipe.label}
      >
        {obj.recipe.label}
      </Text>
      <Flex gap={1} key={obj.recipe.healthLabels}>
        {obj.recipe.healthLabels.filter(
          label => label.includes('Vegetarian')).map(filteredLabel => (
            <Tag
              key={filteredLabel}
              textTransform='uppercase'
              fontSize={10}
              bgColor='yellow.400'
              color='gray.900'
            >
              Vegetarian
            </Tag>
          ))}
        {obj.recipe.healthLabels.filter(
          label => label.includes('Vegan')).map(filteredLabel => (
            <Tag
              key={filteredLabel}
              textTransform='uppercase'                                  
              fontSize={10}                                 
              bgColor='yellow.400'                                  
              color='gray.900'                                  
            >
              Vegan
            </Tag>
          ))}
      </Flex>
      <Flex gap={2} justify='center' wrap='wrap' key={obj.recipe.dietLabels}>
        {obj.recipe.dietLabels.map((dietLabels) => (
          <Tag
            key={dietLabels}
            textTransform='uppercase'                                 
            fontSize={10}                                
            bgColor='green.400'                                
            color='gray.900'                                
          >
            {dietLabels}
          </Tag>
        ))}
      </Flex> 
      <Text textTransform='capitalize'
      >
        Dish: {obj.recipe.dishType}
      </Text>
      <Flex justify='center' gap={2} wrap='wrap'>
        <>
          {obj.recipe.cautions.length> 0 && <Text>Cautions: </Text>}
          {obj.recipe.cautions.map((cautions) => (
            <Tag
              key={obj.recipe.cautions}
              textTransform='uppercase'
              fontSize={10}
              bgColor='purple.400'
              color='gray.800'
            >    
              {cautions}
            </Tag>
          ))}
        </>
      </Flex>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Center bg='pink.600' flexDir="column" h='100%' >
        <Heading size='xl' mt={2} color='white'>Winc Recipe Checker</Heading>
        <TextInput
          changeFn={handleChange}
          matchedRecipe={matchedRecipe}
          />
        <Flex wrap='wrap' gap={8} justify='center' my={2} >
          {list.map((list) => (
            <Card
              bgColor='white'
              overflow='hidden'
              borderRadius={15}
              h='md'
              w='xsm'
              cursor='pointer'
              _hover={{ transform: 'scale(1.03)' }}
              key={list}
              onClick={clickFn(obj.recipe)}
            >
              <CardBody w='18em' p={0} >
                <Stack direction='column' spacing='2px'>
                  <Image />
                  <Flex flexDirection='column' align='center' gap={1}>
                    {list}
                  </Flex>
                </Stack>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </Flex>
      </Center>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically what is happening is that you are triying to pass `obj.recipe` in onClick Function but you have not define the `obj` variable. I don't know if it  something you are supposed to pass from `list` variable from map's prop or is it supposed to a differen variable

i would also suggest you to bind you function like this: `onClick={() => clickFn(obj.recipe)}`

```
{list.map((list) => (
  <Card
    bgColor='white'
    overflow='hidden'
    borderRadius={15}
    h='md'
    w='xsm'
    cursor='pointer'
    _hover={{ transform: 'scale(1.03)' }}
    key={list}
    onClick={clickFn(obj.recipe)} // Here you are passing `obj`, which is not declared any where in your current scop.
  >
    <CardBody w='18em' p={0} >
      <Stack direction='column' spacing='2px'>
        <Image />
        <Flex flexDirection='column' align='center' gap={1}>
          {list}
        </Flex>
      </Stack>
    </CardBody>
  </Card>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is quite descriptive and it's basically saying that in the moment that value is being called it doesn't exist.

I can see that in your code the obj variable is declared in the inner scopes of the array methods you're using. In that case you can't access it's value on an upper/external scope. You will only be able to access obj value inside the function scope it was declared.

For example:

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3]

numbers.map(number => {
  console.log(number) // <-- variable number is only accessible inside this scope
}

console.log(number) // <-- this will throw an error as number will be undefined
```

So when rendering a list you could do like this:

```js
// ...other code
{list.map((item) => ( // <-- DECLARE INDEX HERE
  <Card
    bgColor='white'
    overflow='hidden'
    borderRadius={15}
    h='md'
    w='xsm'
    cursor='pointer'
    _hover={{ transform: 'scale(1.03)' }}
    key={list}
    onClick={clickFn(item.recipe)}
  >
  // ...rest of your code
```

I would also avoid declaring it inline by creating a handler function like this:

```js
// ... initial part of your code
const handleClick = (recipe) => () => {
  clickFn(recipe);
};

// ... other code
list.map((item, index) => (
  <Card
    // ...other card properties
    onClick={handleClick(item.recipe)}
  />
    // ...card content
  </Card>
)
// ...
```

Learn more about javascript scopes in the [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). You can also read more about how to properly call array methods by reading the [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here.

I also see another issue with your code. You're using the objects themselves as key and that isn't recommended as stated in the [React Official Documentation](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys).

Another point is that this, as a component that renders lists can be pretty much optimized and you could define the list component outside this component. I would recommend using the `useMemo` hook to memoize the lists and avoid extra computation and re-renderings. You can read more about it in the [React Official Documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo).

Another important point to watch is that your component is not correct. You've defined the list and then are remapping that list. The fix would be different. You should define the item format and the map through the array calling that item.

So after all that this is how I would write that component:

```js
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { data } from "../utils/data";
import { TextInput } from "../components/ui/TextInput";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Flex,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Center,
  Text,
  Image,
  Stack,
  Tag,
  Heading,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

const Item = ({
  image,
  mealType,
  label,
  healthLabels,
  dietLabels,
  dishType,
  cautions,
}) => {
  return (
    <Card
      bgColor="white"
      overflow="hidden"
      borderRadius={15}
      h="md"
      w="xsm"
      cursor="pointer"
      _hover={{ transform: "scale(1.03)" }}
      key={index}
      onClick={item.recipe}
    >
      <CardBody w="18em" p={0}>
        <Stack direction="column" spacing="2px">
          <Image />
          <Flex flexDirection="column" align="center" gap={1}>
            <Image
              key={image}
              src={image}
              h="10rem"
              w="100%"
              mt={-1}
              borderTopLeftRadius={15}
              borderTopRightRadius={15}
              objectFit="cover"
            />
            <Text textTransform="uppercase" key={mealType}>
              {mealType}
            </Text>
            <Text
              fontSize={18}
              fontWeight="bold"
              textAlign="center"
              key={label}
            >
              {label}
            </Text>
            <Flex gap={1} key={healthLabels}>
              {healthLabels
                .filter((label) => label.includes("Vegetarian"))
                .map((filteredLabel) => (
                  <Tag
                    key={filteredLabel}
                    textTransform="uppercase"
                    fontSize={10}
                    bgColor="yellow.400"
                    color="gray.900"
                  >
                    Vegetarian
                  </Tag>
                ))}
              {healthLabels
                .filter((label) => label.includes("Vegan"))
                .map((filteredLabel) => (
                  <Tag
                    key={filteredLabel}
                    textTransform="uppercase"
                    fontSize={10}
                    bgColor="yellow.400"
                    color="gray.900"
                  >
                    Vegan
                  </Tag>
                ))}
            </Flex>
            <Flex gap={2} justify="center" wrap="wrap" key={dietLabels}>
              {dietLabels.map((dietLabel) => (
                <Tag
                  key={dietLabel}
                  textTransform="uppercase"
                  fontSize={10}
                  bgColor="green.400"
                  color="gray.900"
                >
                  {dietLabel}
                </Tag>
              ))}
            </Flex>
            <Text textTransform="capitalize">Dish: {dishType}</Text>
            <Flex justify="center" gap={2} wrap="wrap">
              {cautions.length > 0 && <Text>Cautions: </Text>}
              {cautions.map((caution) => (
                <Tag
                  key={caution}
                  textTransform="uppercase"
                  fontSize={10}
                  bgColor="purple.400"
                  color="gray.800"
                >
                  {caution}
                </Tag>
              ))}
            </Flex>
          </Flex>
        </Stack>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};

export const RecipeListPage = ({ clickFn }) => {
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearchField(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = (recipe) => () => {
    clickFn(recipe);
  };

  const matchedRecipes = useMemo(
    () =>
      data.hits.filter((obj) =>
        obj.recipe.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
      ),
    [searchField]
  );

  return (
    <Center bg="pink.600" flexDir="column" h="100%">
      <Heading size="xl" mt={2} color="white">
        Winc Recipe Checker
      </Heading>
      <TextInput changeFn={handleChange} matchedRecipe={matchedRecipe} />
      <Flex wrap="wrap" gap={8} justify="center" my={2}>
        {matchedRecipes.map((recipe) => (
          <Item recipe={recipe} key={recipe.label} />
        ))}
      </Flex>
    </Center>
  );
};
```

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention that in order to use the index you need to define it in the map. For example

```js
{list.map((item, index) => (
  <button onClick(item[index]) />
)}
```

As you can see, I've defined the `item` const inside the loop. The list would be an Array of Items. When we are mapping, the first argument is the current value and the second one is the current Array index. In that case, when you run that code, the button you click contains the reference to that specific item in the list.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the tip about useMemo, I never heard about useMemo before. I'm going to try fixing my project.

Comment: Just tried using (displayMatchedRecipe[index].recipe) , this gives the error that index isn't defined.

Comment: I've updated the answer to better solve the problem. I ended not explaining to you how to handle with the list properly. Hope this edited version suits you better.

Comment: Also, having another look I would avoid those healthLabels filters and maps inside the code and would try to get that data before rendering.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanations and patience. Appreciated very much!